# saving text box string value to database c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textbox in which the user can enter their desired username and save it. Once they save it and they happen to revisit their profile page that textbox should be populated with the last username they saved to display and the user will still have the ability to change it and resave. I am fairly new to this and not sure how to start this properly. I am using vs 2012 asp.net mvc 4 c#. Here is my code so far:

```
    @model School.Models.StudentNameModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("_StudentNamePartial", "Profile")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
<fieldset>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StudentName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StudentName)
            <button type="button" value="save" />
        </li>
    </ol>

</fieldset>
```

}

This is my Model:

```
 public class StudentNameModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Student Name")]
    public string StudentName{ get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

GET - To get the student name from database if one exists.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _StudentNamePartial(int id)
    {
        id = WebSecurity.CurrentStudentId;
        var model = new StudentNameModel();
        using (var db = new StudentsDataContext())
        {
            var result = (from u in db.Students
                         where u.ID == id
                         select u.StudentName).FirstOrDefault();
            if(result != null)
                model.StudentName= result;
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

POST - This is where i want to save the new username for the student

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _StudentNamePartial(StudentNameModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           using (var db = new StudentDataContext())
           {
               try
               {

               }
               catch (Exception)
               {

                   throw;
               }
           }
            return RedirectToAction("ProfileAccount");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Also i am having trouble that when i am displaying the username it is not hitting my `Action` method and it always reports that the Object reference is null. Any help will be great. Thanks :D

Comment: You have the `HttpPost` attribute on your controller action where you say it's a `GET`. Also, you shouldn't be using the `Html.DisplayFor` since you're not using a template.

Comment: @CAbbott - i removed the `HttpPost` but i am still not getting a value to show. Also instead of `Html.DisplayFor` what should i be using? I tried `@(Model.StudentName)` but i always get the error of the object being null. Why isn't it hitting my Action method?

Comment: @CAbbott I have this as a partial view so that the part of the username is in a view called `@Html.Partial("_StudentNamePartial")` and then it displays the model and getting the name by `@using(Html.BeginForm("_StudentNamePartial", "Profile")) {..}`

Comment: `http://something/Profile/ProfileAccount`

Comment: When i added that get the error: Argument type 'int' is not assignable to model type `School.Models.StudentNameModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you're trying to render a partial view from a controller action as part of the larger view. In this case, the partial view should be rendered within the `ProfileAccount` view.

You can structure the controller and views like this (rough outline):

**ProfileAccount View Model**:

```
public class ProfileAccountView 
{
    public StudentNameModel StudentName { get; set; }   
}
```

**Profile Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProfileAccount(int id)
{
    // Get whatever info you need and store in a ViewModel
    var model = new ProfileAccountView();

    // Get the student info and store within ProfileAccountView
    // Do your database reads
    model.StudentName = new StudentNameModel { StudentName = result };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProfileAccount(ProfileAccountView profile)
{
    // Do whatever processing here
}
```

**ProfileAccount View**

```
@model School.Models.ProfileAccountView

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProfileAccount", "Profile")) 
{
    @Html.RenderPartial('_StudentNamePartial', Model.StudentName);
    <button type="button" value="save" />
}
```

**_StudentNamePartial Partial View**

```
@model School.Models.StudentNameModel

<fieldset>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StudentName)
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I also have a question - i have a razor view page and for each view file i could only have one model - how can i create a view page that will hold multiple partial views each part make up part of the whole web page.

Comment: My answer sets that up. You create a ViewModel for your "main" view that holds ViewModels of all the partial views you want to render from the main view.